# Delphi 2007: SSL ignore check certificate and 404 error

Tags: rest, delphi, ssl

I'm having a rest connection(username and password protected) and I'd like to ignore SSL certificate check.

In C#:

```
public class TrustAllCertificatePolicy : ICertificatePolicy
{
    private const uint CERT_E_UNTRUSTEDROOT = 0x800B0109;

    public TrustAllCertificatePolicy()
    {
    }

    public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint sp,
        X509Certificate cert, WebRequest req, int problem)
    {
        bool returnValue = problem == 0;

        if ((uint)problem == CERT_E_UNTRUSTEDROOT)
            returnValue = true;
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

I want to do the same in Delphi 2007. Is it possible?

Actually I do:

```
URL:= 'https://hw1200122:8444/WsConduit/ConduitService/SyncData/1';
HttpClient := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
HttpClient.ConnectTimeout := 5000;
HttpClient.ReadTimeout := 5000;
HttpClient.OnAuthorization := httpAuthorization;
HttpClient.MaxAuthRetries := 0;
HttpClient.HTTPOptions := [hoInProcessAuth];
HttpClient.Request.RawHeaders.Clear;
HttpClient.Request.RawHeaders.AddStrings(Self.FHeaders);
HttpClient.Request.BasicAuthentication := true;
HttpClient.Request.Username := Self.FUsername;
HttpClient.Request.Password := Self.FPassword;
httpClient.Request.ContentType := 'application/zip';
LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
httpClient.IOHandler := LHandler;
try    
  respStr := httpClient.Get(URL);
  Result.ResponseCode := httpClient.ResponseCode;
  Result.ResponseStr := respStr;
except
  on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
  begin
    Result.ResponseCode := httpClient.ResponseCode;
    Result.ResponseStr := E.Message;
  end;
end;
```

I get 404 error:

'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'

What's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that url is wrong and the page at the URL does not exists. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_404

Comment: Check that the URL works in a browser first.

Comment: I just tried in my browser (I'm inside a LAN) and the url works and returns a zip file(as required)...

Comment: The 404 error is clearly saying the resource does not exists, double check your URL. It's case sensitive in most servers. If not, check your server log to see if you can find some information about why the server is replying with a 404 error for that particular request. Compare it (the server log info) with a successful request.